# Where and how ROLES are defined when using LDAP and Spring security

Tags: security, authentication, spring-security, ldap, role-base-authorization

I am using Spring Security and authenticating from an LDAP database. The authentication works fine, but I am not able to utilize roles!

In spring-security.xml there is this tag:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/app/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

My question is, where is "ROLE_USER" defined? How is a user made to belong to a particular role? Does this happen in the LDAP database? If yes, then how do I do that? I know little about LDAP. Is it another configuration file where I define roles?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways we can assign a role to a user after LDAP authentication.

1. We can divide users in different groups according to their roles in the LDAP database and map those groups to different roles.

See here : [How to Map AD Groups to User Role Spring Security LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798607/how-to-map-ad-groups-to-user-role-spring-security-ldap)

2. We can authenticate the user using LDAP authentication and authorize using our local database.

**Configuration**:

```
    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticator">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch">
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="searchBase"
                        value="ou=example,dc=springframework,dc=org" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="searchFilter"
                        value="(uid={0})" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="contextSource"
                        ref="contextSource" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator"
        ref="myLDAPAuthPopulator" />
</beans:bean>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Implementation of **myLDAPAuthPopulator**:

```
@Component("myLDAPAuthPopulator")
public class MyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator   {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
    DirContextOperations userData, String username) {

List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

List<String> roleList = userDao.getRoles(username);
if (!roleList.isEmpty()) {
     for (String role : roleList) {
        System.out.println(role);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
}
else
{
 //We know that user is authenticated. So you can add a role here and save it in the database. 
}
return authorities;
}
```

Comment: amant singh, thank you for answering. So, this means I should assign users to roles outside ldap, in the application database? Whenever we have a new user, they will be setup in LDAP as well as in the application database? Will give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: ldap has groups, so should not we use them directly in some or the other way. A group should imply a role. Right. This will simplify the authorization to great extent. Does not spring support this - authorization using ldap groups(roles).