# How to convert Spring XML to Java annotation config (authentication manager)

Tags: java, xml, spring, ldap, user-roles

My question is based on the following topic:
[How to Map AD Groups to User Role Spring Security LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798607/how-to-map-ad-groups-to-user-role-spring-security-ldap/47451140#47451140)

What I'm trying to do is to convert the XML configuration of 'authentication manager' to Java annotation config, since my team decided on not using XML-configs at all.

Is there a simple solution to do so? I.e.: Are there annotation equivalents for setting up 'customUserContextMapper'?

If not, are there general rules on how to apply XML-configurations in the annotations-domain?

Thank you!